# How to filter markers in Mapbox Sdk

Tags: android, filter, sdk, mapbox, markers

I'm creating an Android app using MapBox. I've already set up a simple map functionality with markers sourced from .json file. Next step is filtering the markers on the map, just like in this gl-js example here:
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-markers/

I can't find any sdk examples anywhere, and since this is my first app I really can't figure it out on my own. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out this example https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/multiple-expressions-temperature-change/ that features two layers that fetch a min or max temperature from the data source and display it.

The filtering part is done [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/71f584cc4df23849937ece2c8acb0c73268a805e/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/dds/ExpressionIntegrationActivity.java#L264-L266):

```
      // Only display Maximum Temperature in this layer
      maxTempLayer.setFilter(eq(get("element"), literal("All-Time Maximum Temperature")));
      loadedMapStyle.addLayer(maxTempLayer);
```

Filters accept [expressions](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/expressions/) as arguments, and here `Expression.eq` is used to compare "element" from the GeoJSON data source (referenced with the `Expression.get`) with the "All-Time Maximum Temperature" value. If it resolves to `true`, the feature is going to be displayed, otherwise, it's going to be hidden.

Comment: thanks Łukasz, apologies for really delayed acceptance for this solution. Essentially that's what it's about, for anyone who is looking for a more elaborate example I found it here in the meantime: https://github.com/mapbox/store-locator-android/issues/29